# PostgreSQL Data insertion

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with 4 column. There are thousands of data. The column names are

serial || name || X || Y

From 500 I made a mistake and put the X data into Y field and Y data into X field.

Can I change the data making a range condition where serial no in greater than 500 or serial no equals to 500 to 1000?

Comment: This question is not about GIS.  If made a little clearer it would be fine on SO I believe.

Comment: I am using PostGIS extension of Postgresql. That is why I asked here as I usually asked GIS related question here. Do I delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by standard SQL:

> UPDATE tablename SET  X=Y,Y=X WHERE SERIAL>499 AND SERIAL<1001;

Run only once, or again to undo :-)